# do cookies from all websites get sent on any HTTP request?

Tags: http, cookies

Say I have collected 3 cookies that keep track of my Facebook session, Gmail session and a persistent cookie from a random website.

When I navigate to Facebook, do all cookies currently stored in my browser get sent over HTTP?

Best,

Georges

Comment: No. Otherwise `nasty_hackers.ru` would be able to see your banking cookies and order themselves lots of expensive toys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in a comment, a website only receives cookie with corresponding cookie-domain and cookie-path. It would be really unsecure to send every cookie in the browser to every website visited (and it will also cause performance issues, think about the bandwith used to transfer these useless huge amount of cookies...)